# Axios response in br encoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, cheerio

I am trying to do web scraping from https://coinmarketcap.com/ and I am using the NodeJS libraries cheerio and axios for scraping.

This is my code:

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const axios  = require("axios")

const dataScrapper = () =>{
    const config = {
        method:"get",
        url:"https://coinmarketcap.com/",
    }
    axios(config)
    .then((response) =>{
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
        const selector = "#__next > div > div.main-content > div.sc-1a736df3-0.PimrZ.cmc-body-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sc-f7a61dda-2.efhsPu > table > tbody > tr"
        console.log($.html())
        $(selector).each((index,ele) =>{
            console.log(ele)
            console.log(index)
        }) 
    }).catch((error) =>{
        console.log(error)
    })
}

dataScrapper()
```

I'm getting output like this:

[image: Output]

What is the solution?

Comment: This code works fine for me.

Comment: @ggorlen but why mine is not working

Comment: If I knew I'd let you know. Did you try running it on another terminal or on a cloud sandbox, or try printing just the data you want rather than the whole HTML? That said, data is probably loaded asynchronously with JS, so Axios/Cheerio won't help much there. What data are you trying to get, anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### In v1.2.1, it is fixed this error.

You need to add the `Accept-Encoding` in axios get() header with `text/html; charset=UTF-8`

```
const axios = require("axios")
const cheerio = require("cheerio")
const express = require("express")

async function getPriceFeed() {
    try {
        const siteUrl = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
        const response = await axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: siteUrl,
            headers : { 'Accept-Encoding': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
        })
        console.log(response.data)
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
        const selector = "#__next > div > div.main-content > div.sc-1a736df3-0.PimrZ.cmc-body-wrapper > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.sc-f7a61dda-2.efhsPu > table > tbody > tr"
        console.log($.html())
        $(selector).each((index,ele) =>{
            console.log(ele)
            console.log(index)
        }) 

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }
}
getPriceFeed()
```

Screen capture in VS code
[image]

Result

```
... removed
    Element {
      parent: [Circular *2],
      prev: [Element],
      next: null,
      startIndex: null,
      endIndex: null,
      children: [Array],
      name: 'td',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
      type: 'tag',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {}
    }
  ],
  name: 'tr',
  attribs: [Object: null prototype] { class: 'sc-428ddaf3-0 bKFMfg' },
  type: 'tag',
  namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
  'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined },
  'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { class: undefined }
}
99
```

How about use other web crawler library like a [puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)? It give more easy to handle xpath()

This is demo code by puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");

(async () => {
  const url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/";

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto(url);
  const body = await page.evaluate(() => document.body.outerHTML);
  await browser.close();
  const $ = cheerio.load(body);
  const names = [];
  $(".cmc-link > div > div > p").each((i, item) => {
    const $item = $(item);
    const name = $item.text();
    names.push({
      name
    });
  });
  console.log(names);
})();
```

Result

```
$ node get-data.js
[
  { name: 'Bitcoin' },
  { name: 'Ethereum' },
  { name: 'Tether' },
  { name: 'BNB' },
  { name: 'USD Coin' },
  { name: 'Binance USD' },
  { name: 'XRP' },
  { name: 'Dogecoin' },
  { name: 'Cardano' },
  { name: 'Polygon' }
]
```

Comment: But I saw the tutorial it's working fine there

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar, Which tutorial for `axios` and `cheerio`? can you share the tutorial URL?

Comment: https://youtu.be/5YCuUCRS_Ks this is the URL

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar, thanks you , you are right Axios can do it. I updated to add axios version too.

Comment: It's working but sometimes it works and sometimes it's not

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar, which part is not sometimes, can you makes a screen capture it and update into your question.

Comment: @AbhishekPoddar, the `puppeteer` is much stable instead of `cheerio` can you try it, this is [my example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668982/can-anyone-tell-me-what-is-happening-here/74670219#74670219).